# Find rotation angle for affine transform

Tags: opencv, affinetransform

Lets say I want to compare two images..for that both image have to be aligned

See :https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D4sD.png

I can do affine tranform on second image to align it properly but how to find the rotation angle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

- [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) for both image.
- Consider largest or smallest line from two input image.
- Now calculate angle using the equation

  ```
    double Angle = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180.0 / CV_PI;
  ```

Comment: If one of the image is taken from mobile it will not return me the exact contour..